# Sharing va_list between my functions and vprintf-like library functions

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I would like to add some special processing to formatted printing (with variadic arguments), and I found that the use of `va_list`s in my code does not comply with the C standard. Although it does not cause any error when compiled with GCC, I would like it to be compliant. The following is a simplified version:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct S_ {
    int i;
    va_list *v;
} S;

void fb( S* s )
{
    int x = va_arg( *s->v, int );             // Line A
    vfprintf( stdout, "c:%c s:%s\n", *s->v ); // Line B
    int y = va_arg( *s->v, int );             // Line C
    fprintf( stdout, "d:%d\n", s->i * x * y );
}

void fa( int i, ... )
{
    S s = { i };
    va_list v;
    va_start( v, i );
    s.v = &v;
    fb( &s );
    va_end( v );
}

void main()
{
    fa( 1, 2, 'c', "string", 3 );
}
```

The [standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf:) says on page 249:

> If access to the varying arguments is desired, the called function
> shall declare an object (generally referred to as ap in this
> subclause) having type va_list. The object ap may be passed as an
> argument to another function; if that function invokes the va_arg
> macro with parameter ap, the value of ap in the calling function is
> indeterminate and shall be passed to the va_end macro prior to any
> further reference to ap. (It is permitted to create a pointer to a
> va_list and pass that pointer to another function, in which case the
> original function may make further use of the original list after the
> other function returns.)

As I understand, there is no problem if Line A is followed by Line B since the caller (`fb`) uses `va_arg` before invoking the callee (`vfprintf`). I suppose (though did not find it in the text) the reason for allowing this is that the `va_list` is in the scope of the caller, therefore any change done by `va_arg` will be reflected in the object's state when it is passed to the callee (`vfprintf`).

However, I reckon that Line B followed by Line C is not in line with the standard since the callee (`vfprintf`) received a `va_list`, not a `va_list*`, therefore the value of `*s->v` is indeterminate after Line B, and should not be used as in Line C (rather it should be closed with `va_end`). I suppose (though did not find it in the text) the reason for not allowing the use of `va_list` in the caller (`fb`) after the callee (`vfprintf`) returned is that `*s->v` may have been (depending on the implementation) copied to a local variable of `vfprintf` (at the function call), and in this case, since that copy is destroyed when `vfprintf` returns, the changes it made (consuming a `char` and a `char*`) are not reflected in the original object, so `y` will not be assigned `3` but `'c'` (probably in some distorted way as a `char` is narrower than an `int`).

Unfortunatelly, I cannot make `vfprintf` accept `va_list*` but need to "mix it in" (possibly call `va_arg` before and after calling it with the same `va_list`).

**Is my argument correct and my code incorrect? If so, how can I fix it?**

Comment: In this example, the format string is fixed, so you know the number of arguments and their types, and you can manually extract the arguments individually and pass them to printf() instead of using vprintf(). Do you need them in the case of a dynamic format string?

Comment: @newacct Yes. Although the format strings are known at compile time, there are many of them, and I wouldn't like to manually create an adjustment function for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct and your code is incorrect. Now, it might happen to work on some architectures and not work on some architectures. For example, if an architectures implements `va_list` as a pointer to underlying state, then when it's passed to a function and that function updates the iteration state, that might be visible in the calling scope, and then it would work for you to continue the iteration there. But if the architectures implements it as some kind of struct which has the iteration state by value, then when it's passed to a function and that function updates the iteration state, that will not be visible in the calling scope, so your code would not work. That's what happens with undefined behavior -- there is no guarantee that it works or does not work.

I see no general way to achieve this other than to basically re-implement `vfprintf()`, but take and operate on a `va_list *` rather than a `va_list`. Once you passed a `va_list` by value to a function, you cannot do `va_arg` on that `va_list` in the calling scope anymore. In the C standard's section on `vfprintf()`, it has a footnote that confirms this:

> As the functions vfprintf, vfscanf, vprintf, vscanf, vsnprintf,
> vsprintf, and vsscanf invoke the va_arg macro, the value of arg after
> the return is indeterminate.

`va_copy()` doesn't help here. You can't `va_copy()` after the call to `vfprintf()`, because the `va_list` is already indeterminate at that time. And if you `va_copy()` before the call to `vfprintf()`, the copied `va_list` would still be in the state before the arguments used for the `vfprintf()` are read. So you would need to somehow "skip over" the arguments used for the `vfprintf()`, in order to get to the argument after those arguments. In order to do that, you would need to know the number of arguments used for the `vfprintf()` and their types. So basically you would need to re-implement the format string parsing logic of `vfprintf()` to do that. (And if you're going to do that, you might as well just re-implement `vfprintf()` to take a `va_list *`.)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was afraid of.

Answer (score 0):

Do not share! Copy:

```
typedef struct S{
    int i;
    va_list v;
} S;

void fb( S* s )
{
    int x = va_arg( s->v, int );             // Line A
    vfprintf( stdout, "c:%c s:%s\n", s->v ); // Line B
    int y = va_arg( s->v, int );             // Line C
    fprintf( stdout, "d:%d\n", s->i * x * y );
    va_end(s -> v);
}

void fa( int i, ... )
{
    S s = { i };
    va_list v;
    va_start( v, i );
    va_copy(s.v, v);
    fb( &s );
    va_end( v );
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this solved the incompliance. The problem between Line B and Line C still exists: `s->v` is a `va_list`, so I should call `va_end` on it before `va_arg`. Moreover, `va_end` has to be called by the same function which called `va_start` / `va_copy` on the given `va_list`.

Comment: @z32a7ul you cant "reuse" or share the same `va_list` you need to copy it. Your code is invalid and I would advise to calm down, as my answer is showing it how it **has** to be done. Your code with pointers to va_list obejet is a big undefined behaviour

Comment: Yes, you can share a `va_list` with pointers, please refer to the last sentence I quoted from the standard: "It is permitted to create a pointer to a va_list and pass that pointer to another function, in which case the original function may make further use of the original list after the other function returns." The problem is caused by not using a pointer when calling `vfprintf`, and I know it's UB, that's exactly why I asked this question. BTW, I am absolutely calm, it's your wording "big undefined behaviour" that hints at strong emotions.